# xgboost: need label when data is a matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have been stuck for hours trying to run XGboost with R. I have a training data and test data containing around 40 columns and the last column is the target column. It is a 0,1 nominal value. I am running this code which I got from https://www.kaggle.com/michaelpawlus/xgboost-example-0-76178/code.

```
require(xgboost)
library(xgboost)

train  <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = T)
test   <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = T)

feature.names <- names(train)[2:ncol(train)-1]

 clf <- xgboost(data        = data.matrix(train[,feature.names]),
               label       = train$target,
               nrounds     = 100, # 100 is better than 200
               objective   = "binary:logistic",
               eval_metric = "auc")

 cat("making predictions in batches due to 8GB memory limitation\n")
 submission <- data.frame(ID=test$ID)
 submission$target1 <- NA 
 for (rows in test) {
    submission[rows, "Succeed"] <- predict(clf, data.matrix(test[rows,feature.names]))
 }

 varimp_clf <- xgb.importance(feature_names=feature.names,model=clf)

 xgb.plot.importance(varimp_clf)
```

This is the errors I am getting

> Error in xgb.get.DMatrix(data, label, missing, weight) : 
>     xgboost: need label when data is a matrix
>
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, target1, value = NA) : 
>     replacement has 1 row, data has 0
>
> Error in predict(clf, data.matrix(test[rows, feature.names])) : 
>     object 'clf' not found

Comment: can you post the `str(train$target)` for your data?

Comment: I got "NULL" result

Comment: This is the cause for your error. your `label` should be of equal length as number of data points and not NULL. check why `target` column for `train` data is NULL.

Comment: Thanks my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Check your input data. Is your last column named target? It sounds like it isn't.